# Importing Dynamically modules in python 3 using importlib.import_module()

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-importlib

I'm trying to import modules dynamically as the request comes to flask service. My folder structure is `root/1/main.py` and I have another folder `root/2/main.py`.
I have to import main.py in flask service as per the id(1 or 2). But when I'm doing using `importlib.import_module('.main', package=path)` in my flask service where `path = 'root/id'`. id comes through rest service either 1 or 2. When I do this the whichever import statement present in `main.py` are importing only once. main.py is same in both 1 and 2 folders, there is a slight function changes not the import statements.

My `main.py` in `root/1/main.py`

```
from Service import *
from DB import *
print("Hello user 1")
```

`main.py` in `root/2/main.py`

```
from Service import *
from DB import *
print("Hello user 2")
```

So whichever I make request using id for the 1st time and when I do next request using different id it doesn't import the other modules present in main.py.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Sounds weird to me. Instead why not keep one main.py and add the `id` logic inside another script, then load that script inside `main.py`. Why not ?

Comment: @YOLO Even if I do that It is not able to import Service and DB modules for the 2nd time.

Comment: can you share the structure of your project.